# Sub-samples of different populations

Tags: mixed-model, predictive-models

Suppose i have a sample $S = \{(x_1,y_1),...,(x_n,y_n)\}$ where $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $y_i \in \mathbb{R}$

Suppose further that we know that $S$ is composed (in a way unknown to us) of two different populations.

Some questions:

1) If we know that in each such populations $y_i$ is a linear function of $x_i$, can we expect any reasonable outcome by fitting linear models?

2) If no extra data is given about the generation of the sample. What kind of predictive modeling strategy can be applied to this data?